# recovery script for oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have been told I need to create an sql script that recreates all of the tables/procedures/triggers/views/sequences, etc of my current database. Does anybody have any idea how I go about doing this? It is an oracle 10g express database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL](http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora9i/DDLgen2.shtml) is your friend.

And then invest some time in learning a source control tool such as SVN or GIT.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go old school and do a no rows export via the exp command.

Setting ROWS=N in the exp parameter file will mean metadata only is exported, no actual data.  You would use the imp command to restore that metadata.

Be aware exp generates a binary dump file - if you want SQL scripts use DBMS_METADATA as mentioned by Gary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't fancy getting to grips with DBMS_METADATA then you can use Oracle's free developer tool called [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index-098778.html) which can create this script for you in a few clicks, either for the whole database, an object type, or just one object.

I'm all for learning the DBMS packages but in this case you'll be done and enjoying a hot beverage of your choice in less then the time it'll take to read up about GET_DEPENDENT_DDL.